# What is the (secular) history of Samaria?

Tags: middle-east, palestine

What is 'the history' of the Samaria sub-region of the Province of Judaea from the Roman Empire days through the dissolution of the Empire up to the Middle Ages [roughly]?

I usually find what I'm looking for and move on but would love to have some "pro" help with this little query. I have found it annoyingly difficult to get a search engine to find real, responsible, professional historical writings on this.

What I run into is a massive echo chamber of religiously-burdened thin, poorly sourced fragmented histories that are dominated by either/both Biblical Jewish/Christian histories. Wash/rinse/repeat. If I didn't know better I should think the people group and/or geo region had gone through various name changes complicating the matter, but I have no evidence of that obfuscating results.

This is not a study of ethnicity, per se, though that aspect *is* interesting especially since some of the big genetic DNA/analysis firms seem to show good data suggesting that the region did have more Israelis than some earlier historical sketches want to portray.

That aside, I am interested in the size, growth, events & characteristics of the "Samaritan" populace and their spread or movements over the centuries in question [maps would be so valuable].

If anyone has book titles, or links or other reference data I can take it from there.

EDITS: Trying to respond to questions:
I want to learn the history of the population of Samaria in terms of their population size, spread, migration (if any) from 6CE through 1099CE. I do not need additional sources for “the origins of people groups extant within the Samaria borders by the beginning of 1sr Century CE”. I do not need religious developments of the various peoples who were extant in the stated territory by beginning of 6CE.

Comment: Requests for sources used to be disallowed (I suppose they still are but I haven't been very actively following for a while), perhaps you can formulate some more specific questions? (e.g. what is known about the population of Samaritans, their geographic spread, etc)

Comment: Could you clarify the exact problems you encountered, a bit? EG, the biggest difference between Jews & Samaritans _is_ religion (am also unsure how you use "Israelis" here)? So a focus on the people will include that angle, and there are works that aren't overly religious in their own nature (such academic works currently I'd use for an A, but your title suggests a focus on geographical region but the body seems to inquire mainly about the people's history?) Perhaps quote 1–3 of your finds & explain how they are _not_ what you look for?

Comment: Could you also clarify the period you are interested in: dissolution of what Empire are you talking about? (The Eastern Roman Empire, aka Byzantine Empire, continued to exist until mid 15th century.) Also, when do you think the Middle Ages begin? From my viewpoint, they begin with the end of the Western Roman Empire...

Comment: @MoisheKohan If you look at the edit history there were more concise dates in an earlier version of the question.

Comment: @justCal: I see, so the intended time period is from 66 CE till the 10th Century. I find this at odd with "from the Roman Empire days through the dissolution of the Empire up to the Middle Ages." Oh well...

Comment: IMHO, the period in question should be split in **three**: until Bar Kokhb rebellion (132CE), then until  after Arab conquest circa 636CE (the "Byzantine" period), and the "Arab" period after 636CE.   For the 2nd period you can start by reading for instance [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_revolts) Wikipedia article about Samaritan revolts against the Byzantine rule. Consider also reading this book: Alan David Crown, The Samaritans, Mohr Siebeck, 1989, which includes coverage of the region during the period you are interested in.

Comment: Lastly, regarding the "Samaria" subregion, I doubt there will be any source that specific.

Comment: Thank you Moishe

Comment: You mention in your question the Samaritans. Are you asking about the Samaritans or Samaria as a whole? Because the Samaritans weren't the only people who lived in Samaria. The Samaritans were named after the region, which was named after the city.